# How to Add existing entity as a new Entity with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to create a copy my object in my DB with using Entity Framework

first I got my "Book" from DB

```
var entity1 = new testEntities();
var book= entity1.Books.First();
entity1.Dispose();
```

then, I tried to add this object as a new object

```
var entity2 = new testEntities();
book.Id = 0;
entity2.SaveChanges();
entity2.Dispose();
```

Also I trid to initilize EntityKey of Book
it didnt work

Is there any way doing this without creating new Book and copy properties from old one?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to fetch the entity, change the `EntityState` to `Added` in the `ObjectStateManager` and call `SaveChanges`:

```
var entity1 = new testEntities();
var book = entity1.Books.First();

ObjectStateEntry bookEntry = entity1.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(book);
bookEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Added);

entity1.SaveChanges();
```

This will copy your 'book'.